# Why does UIScrollView stop scrolling?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am editing this question because i found the exact cause of this problem. Sorry for previous.

I have `UIScrollView` on my `ViewController`. I am using stroryboard, ios6, xcode 4.5. Setting the `scrollView` `ContentSize` in `viewDidAppear` method.

I am `presenting` one `modelViewController`. When i disappear that model view controller, my `scrollview` stops working. I check in log the `content size` in `viewDidAppear` method, it was showing correct size (bigger that frame size). Still it stops scrolling.

Why this is happening. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: How are you showing and hiding your container view?

Comment: Container view is subView of Scroll view? It seems scroll view and Container View is same level.

Comment: i take the IBOutlet of Container view and by it showing and hiding.

Comment: no container view is not subview of Scrollview

Comment: A scrollview that stops scrolling is usually because its contentSize is smaller than its frame size. In order to detect what is happening, you might want to derive your own scrollview, override its setFrame and setContentSize methods and put breakpoints in them.

Comment: @BH4451 i'm having the same issue. Have you found the solution?

Comment: @Bhushan facing same issue have you found solution?

Answer (score 0):

> How do you hide `ContanerView`?

Try this:

Hide:    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:ContanerView]; 
Unhide:    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:ContanerView];